# Method save does not exist laravel

Tags: sql, laravel

i'am trying to change the satuts in database with clicking on button , so i got this error :

```
Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::save does not exist.
```

this is the controller :

```
public function completedUpdate(Request $request, rendezvous $rdv )
{
        $data = DB::table('rdv')->get();
        foreach($data as $rdv) {
            if ( $rdv->Etat_de_rdv == 'en_attente' ) {
      DB::table('rdv')->where('Etat_de_rdv','en_attente')->update(['Etat_de_rdv' => 'Accepter']);
            }
        }
        $data->Etat_de_rdv = $request->changeStatus;
        $data->save();
        return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Status changed!');
    
}
```

this is the view :

```
@foreach($pat as $lo)
@if ($lo->IDD== $med->ID)
<h3> {{ $lo->Nom_et_prénom  }} </h3>
<p>{{ $lo->Numéro_de_téléphone }}</p>
<p>{{ $lo->date}}</p>
<p>{{ $lo->time }}</p>
@if($lo->Etat_de_rdv == "en_attente") 
<form action="{{ route('completedUpdate', $lo->id) }}" method="POST">
{{ csrf_field() }}
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="changeStatus" value="Accepter">Active</button>
</form>
@else
<form action="{{ route('completedUpdate', $lo->id) }}" method="POST">
{{ csrf_field() }} 
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="changeStatus" value="Charger">Inactive</button>
 </form>
```

and this is the route :

```
Route::post('/completedUpdate/{id}', 'rendezv@completedUpdate')->name('completedUpdate');
```

Comment: Well not on Illuminate\Support\Collection no. You should call save on Model instances! Or Mass update using a query: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#mass-update

Comment: how ? @onlineThomas

Comment: Do the saving inside your loop.

Comment: @onlineThomas oh this is work but i got another error `The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.
.`

Comment: as per the first comment ... even if you iterated that collection you don't have Eloquent Models, you have `stdClass` objects, they are not models and do not have a `save` method

Answer (score 1):

`Model::create` is a simple wrapper around `$model = new MyModel(); $model->save()`

A raw `DB::table` query builder isn't an Eloquent model and thus doesn't have those automatic parameters.

An example of insert data in a `DB` like :

```
DB::table('users')->insert( ['email' => 'john@example.com', 'votes' => 0] );
```

Using `get()` returns a [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-collections). Despite the fact you are passing in a 'unique' ID, the `id`, it will still return a collection. The collection will simply have one element in it.

Subsequently, your code will not work as you have experienced, or at least not without a few changes to make `$data` reference the first element in the collection.

```
$data = DB::table('rdv')->get(); // <= error here
  foreach($data as $rdv) {
    if ( $rdv->Etat_de_rdv == 'en_attente' ) { // <= also an error
      DB::table('rdv')->where('Etat_de_rdv','en_attente')->update(['Etat_de_rdv' => 'Accepter']);
      }
  }
$data->Etat_de_rdv = $request->changeStatus;
$data->save(); // <= there are no save method on query builder
```

Here is an example how the `save()` method works with Model :

```
$id = 1;
$data = Rdv::find($id);
$data->Etat_de_rdv = $request->changeStatus;
$data->save();
```

Comment: Query builder returns `stdClass` objects not models, there is no `save` method on them